# Is StreamGeometry a standard mini-language or is it proprietary to Microsoft?

Tags: xaml, svg

Is the [Path Markup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx) from a standard or internal to Microsoft? Has any one written code out there that, say, translates SVG markup into Path Markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As showed in this link, [Path Markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html) is a w3c standard.